# Check-Through with AirChina

Tags: luggage, services, air-china

I have booked my flight via Air China from Frankfurt (Germany) to Osaka(Japan) with one stop in Beijing(China). 
Can anybody tell me if there is a Check-Through service and if so what is your experience with it?

Both flights are via Air China

Comment: All on one ticket, or did you book two different tickets one for each leg? Also, how long is the layover?

Comment: I stay in Beijing for about 2 1/2 Hours

Comment: I read the ticket as one also it says it's the same Terminal

Comment: are both flights operated by Air China? in my experience as long as both flights are operated by CA then you will be ticketed through, otherwise there is a chance you need to be checked in again in Beijing despite both flights being ticketed by CA

Comment: Yes both flights are operated by Air China

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both flights are Air China and you only have been issued one ticket (with one reservation code), then there is a very good probability that you won't need to pick up your luggage and register them again in Beijing. You will also potentially get your boarding pass for the second flight before the first flight (sometime, the seat won't be assigned yet).

Still, when you arrive in Beijing, double check to see if your luggage aren't on the belt. I have seen situations where luggage were supposed to make their way through but still they were waiting on the belt :)

Comment: You were right, our luggage has nicely been checked through